# Storing User input of values to display minimum difference

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Have a program that calculates the minimum difference between a group of inbuilt numbers in an array(so in this case minimum difference is 3 since min difference in the numbers is between 4 and 1). I want the program to instead take in values from the user using a for loop to set the amount of values entered to 6. This is the current code below:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Mindifference {


Scanner numinput= new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] a = new int[] {4, 9, 1, 32, 13};
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int minDiff = a[1]-a[0];
    for (int i = 2 ; i != a.length ; i++) {
        minDiff = Math.min(minDiff, a[i]-a[i-1]);
    }
    System.out.println(minDiff);    
}
    }
```

Comment: What is the output? What output did you expect?

Comment: I want the output to be the calculated value of the minimum difference. so the same as what this current code does, it prints out 3 since the smallest minimum difference between those numbers is between 1 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rudimentary implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinDifference
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] inputs = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

      inputs[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    scanner.close();
    Arrays.sort(inputs);
    int minDiff = inputs[1] - inputs[0];
    for (int j = 2; j != inputs.length; j++)
    {
      minDiff = Math.min(minDiff, inputs[j] - inputs[j - 1]);
    }
    System.out.printf("The minimum difference is %d", minDiff);
  }
}
```